# Building nested conditional expression-trees

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I'm trying to dynamically build some sql-queries depending on a given config to only query data needed:

When writing plain linq it would look like this:

```
var data = dbContext
.TableOne
.Select(t1 => new TableOneSelect
{
    TableOneId = t1.TableOneId,
    TableOneTableTwoReference = new[] { TableOne.FirstTableTwoReference.Invoke(t1) }
        .Select(t2 => new TableTwoSelect
        {
            TableTowId = (Guid?)t2.TableTwoId,
            // ... some more properties of t2
        }).FirstOrDefault(),
    // ... some more properties of t1
});
```

whereas `TableOne.FirstTableTwoReference.Invoke(t1)` is defined

```
public static Expression<Func<TableOne, TableTwo>> FirstTableTwoReference => (t1) => t1.TableTwoReferences.FirstOrDefault();
```

Currently I have the following for building the TableOne-part dynamically:

```
public Expression<Func<TableOne, TableOneSelect>> Init(TableOneConfig cfg)
{
    var memberBindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
    var selectType = typeof(TableOneSelect);
    var newExpression = Expression.New(selectType);
    var theEntity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TableOne), "t1");

    // decide if the property is needed and add to the object-initializer
    if (cfg.Select("TableOneId"))
        memberBindings.Add(Expression.Bind(selectType.GetProperty("TableOneId"), Expression.Property(theEntity, nameof("TableOneId"))));

    // ... check other properties of TableOneSelect depending on given config

    var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, memberBindings);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<tblTournament, EventResourceSelect>>(memberInit, theEntity);
}
```

same for `TableTwo` (different properties and different db-table).

This I can dynamically invoke like this

> dbContext.TableOne.Select(t => TableOneHelper.Init(cfg).Invoke(t1));

whereas `Invoke` is the one from `LinqKit`.

But I get stuck with the inner part for the `TableOneTableTwoReference` where I need to make an enumeration to call the `Init` of `TableTwoHelper` but I don't get the point how this can be achieved.

I guess `Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(TableTwo), ...)` would be step one. But I still get stuck in how to pass `t1.TableTwoReferences.FirstOrDefault()` to this array calling the `Select` on.

Comment: Something that may help you is to remember that `x.FirstOrDefault()` is equivalent to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(x)`. Then you can use `Expression.Call()`.

Comment: @vyrp My real problem it is even more complicated as of the first `FirstOrDefault()` is an `Expression<Func<TableOne, TableTwo>>` as well and I need to invoke this to fill the array. Will update my question

Answer (score 2):

> I guess `Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(TableTwo), ...)` would be step one. But I still get stuck in how to pass `t1.TableTwoReferences.FirstOrDefault()` to this array calling the `Select` on.

As I understand, the question is what is the expression equivalent of

```
new[] { TableOne.FirstTableTwoReference.Invoke(t1) }
```

It's really simple. As you correctly stated, you'll need [`Expression.NewArrayInit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.newarrayinit(v=vs.110).aspx) expression. However, since it expects `params Expression[] initializers`, instead of LINQKit `Invoke` extension method you should use [`Expression.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170(v=vs.110).aspx) method to emit call to `TableOne.FirstTableTwoReference` lambda expression with the outer `theEntity` ("t1") parameter:

```
var t2Array = Expression.NewArrayInit(
    typeof(TableTwo),
    Expression.Invoke(TableOne.FirstTableTwoReference, theEntity));
```

The same way you can emit the `Select` expression:

```
var t2Selector = TableTwoHelper.Init(cfg2);
// t2Selector is Expression<Func<TableTwo, TableTwoSelect>>
var t2Select = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { t2Selector.Parameters[0].Type, t2Selector.Body.Type },
    t2Array, t2Selector);
```

then `FirstOrDefault` call:

```
var t2FirstOrDefault = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new[] { t2Selector.Body.Type },
    t2Select);
```

and finally the outer member binding:

```
memberBindings.Add(Expression.Bind(
    selectType.GetProperty("TableOneTableTwoReference"),
    t2FirstOrDefault));
```

This will produce the equivalent of your "plain linq" approach.

Comment: Out of interest: You are writing `Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Select",...` but this is not working at all. Always getting `No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments.` What's the best workaround for?

Comment: @KingKerosin Not sure why are you getting that error. I've tested it before posting and it worked. `t2Selector.Parameters[0].Type` is `TableTwo`, `t2Selector.Body.Type` is `TableTwoSelect`, so we have `Enumerable.Select<TableTwo, TableTwoSelect>(TableTwo[] array, Func<TableTwo, TableTwoSelect> t2Selector)` which is correct call.

Answer (score 0):

Add the member binding...

```cs
memberBindings.Add(Expression.Bind(selectType.GetProperty("TableOneTableTwoReference"), BuildTableTwoExpression(theEntity)));
```

...and then build `TableTwo`'s expression

```cs
private Expression BuildTableTwoExpression(ParameterExpression t1)
{
    var arrayEx = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(TableTwo), Expression.Invoke(TableOne.FirstTableTwoReference, t1));

    Expression<Func<TableTwo, TableTwoSelect>> selector = (t2 => new TableTwoSelect
    {
        TableTowId = (Guid?)t2.TableTwoId,
        // ... some more properties of t2
    });

    Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TableTwo>, TableTwoSelect>> selectEx =
        ((t1s) => Enumerable.Select(t1s, selector.Compile()).FirstOrDefault());

    return Expression.Invoke(selectEx, arrayEx);
}
```